# How to encode 'Importação de petróleo' string in python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I want to use "Importação de petróleo" in my program.

How can I do that because all encodings give me errors as cannot encode.

Comment: Add `u` in front of your string-literal. `u"..."`

Comment: @kev : it gives me error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: & I dont want to use like this characters in my program. : u'Importa\xe7\xe3o de petr\xf3leo'

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and show us the code there. So that we don't have to guess what you're doing.

Comment: @sam: You're still not showing us your code or your errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing the string `__repr__` with its `__str__`:

```
>>> s = u"Importação de petróleo"
>>> s
u'Importa\xe7\xe3o de petr\xf3leo'
>>> print s
Importação de petróleo
```

There's no problem with `\xe7` and friends; they are just the encoding representation for those special characters. You can't avoid them and you shouldn't need to :)

**A must-to-read link about unicode:** [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Why this answer got downvoted? It solved and cleared the OP problem and doubts, which he expressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644338/how-to-encode-importacao-de-petroleo-string-in-python/9644411#comment12244663_9644338) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644338/how-to-encode-importacao-de-petroleo-string-in-python/9644411#comment12244694_9644394) (hence the link about unicode).

Answer (score 3):

Do this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print 'Importação de petróleo'
```

place

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

on very top of the program (first line).
Also save your code as utf-8 (default if you are using linux)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using characters in a source (.py) file which are outside of the ASCII range, then you will need to specify the encoding at the top of the file, so that the Python lexer knows how to read and interpret the characters in the file.

If this is the case, then, as the very first line of your file, use this:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

(If your file is actually in a different encoding, such as ISO-8859-1, then you will need to use that instead. Python can handle several different character encodings; you just have to tell it what to expect)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a 'u' in front of the string makes it unicode. The documentation here gives details regarding Unicode handling in Python 2.x:-

[Python 2.x Unicode support](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support)

Comment: adding u gaves me u'Importa\xe7\xe3o de petr\xf3leo'. i dont want to use such characters

Comment: Did you try using it in some expression? Try printing it. Refer to @Rik Poggi's answer, that is what you get

Answer (score 1):

As specialscope mentioned, first thing,  you have add this as the first line of your program:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

If you don’t, you’ll get an error which looks something like this:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /tmp/blah.py on line 10, 
but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html 
for details
```

So far, so good. Now, you have to make sure that every string that contains anything besides plain ASCII is prefixed with `u`:

```
print u'Importação de petróleo'
```

But there’s one more step. This is a separate topic, but chances are that you’re going to have to end up *re*-encoding that string before you send it to `stdout` or a file.

Here are the rules of thumb for Unicode in Python:

1. If at all possible make sure that any data you’re working with is in UTF-8.
2. When you read external UTF-8 encoded data into your program, immediately decode it into Unicode.
3. When you send data out of your program (to a file or `stdout`), make sure that you re-encode it as UTF-8.

This all changes in Python 3, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Help on class unicode in module **builtin**:

class unicode(basestring)
 |  unicode(string [, encoding[, errors]]) -> object
 |
 |  Create a new Unicode object from the given encoded string.
 |  encoding defaults to the current default string encoding.
 |  errors can be 'strict', 'replace' or 'ignore' and defaults to 'strict'.
 |

try using "utf8" as the encoding for unicode()

Comment: Slides for a nice talk on unicode at pycon today http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html